# XSLT Functions & how to access the logic within the function

Tags: function, xslt

I am new to XSLT & trying to understand functions. I got an XSLT from another developer & am trying to understand the transformation`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:CMQueryHelper="urn:CMQueryHelper" xmlns:ExternalReference="urn:ExternalReference" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xsi msxsl CMQueryHelper ExternalReference">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <xsl:output method="xml" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="IncidentLocationOrgUnitID" select="CMQueryHelper:GetOrgChartInheritedNodeAttribute($CNode/Incident/Location, 'OrgUnitID')" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone explain what is being done here & how do i access urn:CMQueryHelper & what logic is written inside GetOrgChartInheritedNodeAttribute function??

```
xmlns:CMQueryHelper="urn:CMQueryHelper" ??xmlns:ExternalReference="urn:ExternalReference" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xsi msxsl CMQueryHelper ExternalReference"
```

Comment: here is a user define function you are calling 'CMQueryHelper:GetOrgChartInheritedNodeAttribute()' you may have to sahre that function, it may be in same XSLT or imorted or included one. find out that function definition.

Comment: Thanks Amrendra. It is imported using external reference & i thought we can have access to the function. How does the stylesheet know the logic of the function & execute it??

Answer (score 0):

This is a very peculiar XSLT stylesheet. Its sole effect is to call the external function `CMQueryHelper:GetOrgChartInheritedNodeAttribute()`, and we have no idea from looking at the supplied source what that function might be. XSLT stylesheets are allowed to call external functions, but the mechanisms for doing so depend entirely on which XSLT processor you are using. Often the namespace URI of the function name gives a clue, but not in this case. The fact that the stylesheet declares the Microsoft msxsl namespace might also be a clue, but since it doesn't use that namespace, this could simply be redundant boilerplate.

Note that some XSLT processors, given this stylesheet, will do nothing. All the stylesheeet does is to declare and initialize a variable, and since the value of the variable is never used, an optimizer is quite capable of deciding there's no point in evaluating it.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the response. There is other logic but i copy pasted the function call as i couldn't understand how the xslt processor was able to run the function without any issues & i can't seem to find a way to access the function to check the logic

Comment: First thing we need to know is what XSLT processor you are using.